# Smarty operation in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, smarty

I'm trying to do in Prestashop 1.7 math operation between two smarty variables inside product-discounts.tpl but result is wrong...

```
{$product.regular_price}
```

[output: 12,85 €]

```
{$quantity_discount.discount}
```

[output: 9.8%]

```
{$product.regular_price*$quantity_discount.discount}
```

[output: 117,6] Should be: 12.85*9.8= 125.93

Any idea?

I've tryed:

```
{$product.regular_price|floatval}
```

[output:12] Should be: 12.85

Thanks in advance

Prestashop 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is happening because of comma in price **12,85 €**, so, if you replace the comma with dot then you will get a correct value **125.93**

I think the easiest solution would be by assigning a new variable in tpl file and replace the comma from the `regular_price` **12,85** with a dot.

*By the way, you could also replace comma with dots from the controller* but if you want to perform mathematical operations within the template file you could do it like this:

Firstly, assign `{$product.regular_price}` to `regularPrice` variable along with replacing comma with dot, something like this:

```
{assign var=regularPrice value=$product.regular_price|replace:',':'.'}
```

I hope `$quantity_discount.discount` always contains dot but if there is also a comma instead of dot then,

```
{assign var=quantityDiscount value=$quantity_discount.discount|replace:',':'.'}
```

and, last thing you have to do is multiple both variables `regularPrice` and `quantityDiscount` with each other

```
{assign var=total_price value=$regularPrice * $quantityDiscount}
```

then display `total_price` in tpl file like this:

```
{$total_price}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following
{$product.regular_price_amount*$quantity_discount.discount}

regular_price is used for price display.
If you want to do some mathematical calculation then you can use the regular_price_amount value of the product.